# Why do I get error 255 when returning -1

Tags: shell, exit

I'm new into C++ programming and I have a very basic question.
I've  noticed that when I return `-1` in C++ program and then check the exit status, I get `255`. Why is that?

The code is the most basic:

```
int main()
    {
        return -1;
    }
```

Then, after running the compiled code:

```
echo $?
255
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because in UNIX/POSIX, the exit code of a program is defined to be an unsigned 8-bit value.  Converting -1 to unsigned 8-bit gives 255.

Edit to add:

To give more detail: the wait*() family of system calls in UNIX encode the result of a process into a single 32bit integer.  The 32 bits of that result are further broken up to provide information such as whether the process dumped core, exited due to a signal (and which one), etc.  Of that 32 bits, only 8 are reserved for the exit code of the process and those are interpreted as an unsigned value.

The fork/exec/wait model of UNIX/POSIX is one of its very oldest and most deeply embedded features; if you were designing a new operating system today you might do something different (at least use 64 bits :-)).

On the other hand, practically speaking is it really useful to have >255 exit codes?  I doubt it.  If you really wanted something more powerful I'd suggest that you'd switch to an "exit string", instead of a numeric exit code with a wider range.

Answer (score 9):

To quote from `bash` man page on **EXIT STATUS**

> The exit status of an executed command is the value returned by the
>   waitpid system call or equivalent function.  Exit statuses fall between 
>   0 and 255, though,  as  explained  below, the  shell may use values 
>   above 125 specially.  Exit statuses from shell builtins and compound 
>   commands are also limited to this range. Under certain circumstances, 
>   the shell will use special values to indicate specific failure modes.

So it caps it to that range, I'm actually as surprised as you are.

From the `waitpid (2)` man page:

`WEXITSTATUS(status)`

> returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of  the  least
>   significant  8 bits  of  the  status  argument  that  the  child
>   specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument for a 
>   return statement in main().   This  macro  should only be employed if 
>   WIFEXITED returned true.